# Seeking for outdated intel optimization manuals (2010-2011)

Tags: intel, manual

I am reading *Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Optimization Reference Manual* , from 2014 (not the latest),

but the latencies reported at the end of the manual (*APPENDIX C: INSTRUCTION LATENCY AND THROUGHPUT*) stop at the Sandy architecture.
I need Core 2 duo too but it is absent.

Actually, one can only get the latest edition. at every iteration, they remove "legacies" from their counting.
So I guess I need an older edition, maybe 2010-2011 to get those latencies.

May someone give me a link/ way to get it, please? they didn't answer on the Intel forum.

I know about Agner Fog's measurings but I want those from Intel.
Thanks

Comment: @Mohamad this question is a _very_ poor fit for Programmers - it would be quickly voted down and closed over there, see http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6487#6487 Recommended reading: **[What goes on Programmers.SE? A guide for Stack Overflow](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7182/31260)**

Comment: @gnat: it seems you are right. it is massively voted down. So no place to help me with that problem.. OK.

Answer (score 1):

You could use archive.org to retrieve cached versions of a webpage

*Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Optimization Reference Manual (June 2011)*
https://web.archive.org/web/20110926200348/http://www.intel.com/content/dam/doc/manual/64-ia-32-architectures-optimization-manual.pdf